# Scrollview hiding textfield when keyboard seen

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using swift 3, i have a form of 12 textfields.Once user goes to textfield at bottom of scrollview, the keyboard hides the textfield.So to solve this issue, i added this piece of code below. However the problem with added code below, is when I hide the keyboard am no more capable of scrolling up or down.Scrolling in scrollview somehow becomes disabled.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    registerKeyboardNotifications()
}   

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    unregisterKeyboardNotifications()
}   

func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidShow(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow,
                                           object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                           object: nil)
}    

func unregisterKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}  

func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {      
    print("keyboard seen")
    let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardInfo = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardInfo.cgRectValue.size
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}    

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("keyboard hidden")
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

Comment: Use "IQKeyboardManagerSwift" - library.  Link - https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: You can use TPKeyboardAvoiding library

Comment: check if the content of the scrollview height is lower that the scrollview size height
In that case the scrollView will not scroll unless you set verticalBounce = Yes